# Saving XML to specific location with XML Tools 2 for AppleScript

Tags: xml, applescript

I am using XML Tools 2 (http://www.latenightsw.com/freeware/XMLTools2/index.html) to generate an XML file in AppleScript. I cannot figure out how to save out the generated XML file to a specific location.

```
set theFilename to "test_xml"
set theXML to ¬
    {class:XML element, XML tag:"FinalCutServer", XML contents:{¬
        {class:XML element, XML tag:"request", XML attributes:{reqId:"setMd", entityId:"/asset/STRING_TO_BE_REPLACED"}, XML contents:{¬
            {class:XML element, XML tag:"params", XML contents:{¬
                {class:XML element, XML tag:"mdValue", XML attributes:{fieldName:" Title", dataType:"string"}, XML contents:{"test01"}}}}}}}}

set xmlPath to "Macintosh HD:XMLin:" & theFilename & ".xml" as Unicode text
generate XML theXML saving as xmlPath with generating UTF8
```

Using the above code, returns the following error: 'error "Bad name for file. some object" number -37' and saves it to the root directory on my HD. Is there anyway to save it directly to a specific location or do I need to save it to the root and then move the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this tool at all and can't help you with specific code. But in general applescript commands require file specifiers or alias's for the paths. Your path is a string so it may not be in the proper format... you could try putting the word **file** in front of the variable xmlPath. That would make it a proper applescript-style path.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that! Thanks!!